# Is there any file where I can edit the database connection in between pentaho and postgreSQL

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have installed Alflytics V 5.0 on the Pentaho Server.

When I am made changes in the Configuration tab and trying to save, it shows that "configuration not saved".

My issue is that I am unable to make changes in configuration and extract the data in Alflytics.

So I want to know the file in which we can change the database connection setting for Pentaho server and the PostgreSQL.

I have installed Penthao server on Windows 10 platform.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: your question is not clear.
are you saying how to edit created database connection?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I want to edit the database connection and also I want to know, through which file we save the configuration of Alflytics to the database.

Comment: once you created a connection and share it, one shared.xml file will be created through which you can edit the connection.

Comment: Hello @HelpingHand.. 
I tried to find that file but I am not able to locate that shared.xml file. Is there any other way to change the connection settings?